# ActionScript MDIWindow Resize Issue

Tags: actionscript, resize, window, mdi

I have an MDIWindow for a tutoring extension to BigBlueButton I am writing in ActionScript . I am a novice with ActionScript. Whenever I create this window it is very large. I can not figure out why it does not appear as the declared width and height. Below I have included my declaration. I would appreciate any help you can give. Thanks!

```
<MDIWindow xmlns="flexlib.mdi.containers.*"
       xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
       xmlns:mate="http://mate.asfusion.com/"
       xmlns:components="org.bigbluebutton.modules.example.view.components.*"
       xmlns:views="org.bigbluebutton.modules.example.views.*"
       width="650" height="900" label="StudentInterface" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"
       implements="org.bigbluebutton.common.IBbbModuleWindow" layout="horizontal"
       title="Student Interface!">
```

Comment: Im not familiar with this, but i recommend checking what ever loads this maybe stretching to fit itself